# How to repair encrypted disk image which suddenly stopped recognizing password

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, password, encryption

I was in the middle of remotely backing up to a mounted encrypted sparse bundle (using rsync) when the machine was rebooted.  Since it was an orderly shutdown, presumably the image should have been unmounted properly.  However, now when I try to mount the drive using the correct password, I get the error:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error
```

How can I fix this issue?  I tried using Disk Utility but it seems like until I actually enter the password I can't do anything, but it refuses to recognize the password as correct when I enter it.

I would prefer to not have to throw away the archive and rebuild it from scratch, as it is quite large (terabytes).

Comment: Please add the output of `hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -stdinpass -debug  /path/to/tm.sparsebundle` to your question! Sanitize the output (password/path/names) before adding it.

Comment: @klanomath The output is quite verbose (32kB), is it ok to put that much text right in the question?  Also, I see several places where there are binary values, how can I tell if any of these contain sensitive info that needs sanitization - should I just sanitize everything?

Comment: Simply remove the binary part (replace it with something like [<bin>...</bin>])

Comment: @klanomath `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32391.`

Comment: You might send it to me (klanomath(at)googlemail.com) as  zipped attachment and I will have a look, remove all irrelevant parts and post it here...